# Algorithmic Problem/Code Challenge. JS Function incrementing/decrementing Strings in the lexicographically smallest step possible

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, increment, decrement

**I need a js function, that increments Strings lexicographically, by incrementing or appending letters(A-Z, a-z) only, it gets passed an initial string, and the amount of increments n. It returns an array with n lexicographically ascending strings.**

1. Special characters should not be modified, they may however be appended too or removed when decrementing
2. Increments should also be the smallest step possible, within the minimum at least required string length
3. The total amount of increments, could be passed as an argument, since it is determined in advance.

Incrementation Examples:

"x", 2 times:
[y,z]

"x", 53 times
[xA, xB, xC,...,xz, y, yA]

"$y$", 1 time:
["$z$"]

"$y$", >53 times:
[$y$A - $y$Z, $y$a - $y$z, $z$, $z$A,....]

I managed to create an increment function, If the question ever gets opened again I would post it as a Reply.

**I also require a decrement function. Just like increment, it gets passed an initial string and n. It returns an array, just like increment.**

1. Letters may be incremented/deleted/appended, special characters only deleted.
2. It should decrement the string with using as few additional digits as possible and never go below the empty string
3. Minimum digits used for decrementing is the length of the initial string, it may be more if necessary, see example below.
4. The total amount of decrements, could be passed as an argument, since it is determined in advance.
5. Assume, that we don't pass initial strings that are empty, or only containing the smallest letter "A"

Example: (we assume our letters to only be a,b for these examples)

*"ab" decrement 8 times*

-> 4 digits required minimum

result: ["aabb","aaba","aab","aaaa","aaa","aa","a",""]

*"b$b" decrement 10 times*

-> 3 digits are enough

result: ["b$a", "b$", "b", "abb", "aba", "ab", "aaa", "aa", "a", ""]

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Does the outer quotes removal have anything to do with your question?

Comment: BTW, that is a strange way to increment: "zzz" is incremented to "zzzA", so that means that if you have a z-prefix, it will always stay there, and will eventually grow to longer prefixes of "z". That's not how it usually works.

Comment: (continued) ... That means that if you start with the empty string, and just keep calling that function on the previous returned string, you'll never generate a string that has more than one non-z character! Only the rightmost character can be anything else than "z". Is that really how you want it to work?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the long response time, I am currently on vacation, but thanks for the responses anyway. I want to increment it that way, because only lexicographical order matters to me, further more I want the digits to be as few as possible for as long as possible. The Quotes removal can be ignored I suppose, although it is necessary in my program. I apologize for including it.

Comment: Lastly, I did in fact do some research on the topic, as well as search on SO for answers, but nobody seems to be incrementing strings the way I want to. I found no similar examples anywhere, and no research papers(to the best of my abilities) either. I realize now, that the question could have been formulated better in terms of SO conventions, but I think, the solution that I am looking for is still coming across.

Comment: *"I want the digits to be as few as possible for as long as possible."*: that's exactly my point. You don't achieve that this way. Every time the final digit reaches "z" and you increment, you need to add a digit, That means every 56 times you add a digit. That is certainly *not* the way to keep the digits as few as possible, since there are 56^3 ways to arrange 3 digits, and you will be using a fourth digit already after 56*3 increments! *"nobody seems to be incrementing strings the way I want to."*: I hope you understand why... Can you please review your proposed logic?

Comment: @trincot, you are absolutely right btw. It would be better, that if I knew, I had to increase the length of the string eventually, that I would increment like this: y, ya, yb,... yz, z,za,... instead of y, z, za, zz, zza... but I struggle designing an algorithm like that, especially, the corresponding decrement function ;(

Comment: Ok, but then it would be really good if you would say that in your question, i.e. what the desired result is and how your increment function is *not* doing the right thing, because now you say that it *"...fits my specification more or less."*. I would say it hardly does. It only does it right when only the rightmost digit needs to change. But OK, now I think I get what you want, and I will post an answer within an hour or so.

Comment: I will take down the question for now, and do some more work on it first, since you demonstrated to me my flawed thinking up till now. By first calculating the min and max amount of digits, that I need for n increments. I should be able to write the better increment algorithm at least, and maybe the decrement too eventually.

Comment: No, you can leave it. I will post on answer on the extra info you provided here. Still it would be good to edit it.

Comment: Never mind i just saw your response, I will keep the question up. But i apologize for being so unclear

Comment: *"The total amount of increments/decrements, could be passed as an argument"*: how does that work? Would you pass two numbers with each call of `increment`, but then make sure to adapt them with each next call? I fail to see how this would work in a practical case.

Comment: Let's take the final example: `"$y$", >53 times`. What if I *decrement* 53 times? Or is there a rule that you must first increment before you can decrement?

Comment: Did you see my comments? There are still elements that are not clear in your question...

Comment: I call generateAscendingStrings(n, string) and it gives me an array of lexicographically ascending strings in the way that the examples indicate.

Comment: Regarding Decrement, I am not going to be able to make it the exact inverse of increment. It is going to work the following way. First a function determines how many digits I need to decrement the string n times, then the string is decremented: Example: (Alphabet is only a,b) decrement "ab" 8 times. The first function will determine, that for this we need at least 4 digits, and then it will return an array: ["ab","aabb","aaba","aab","aaaa","aaa","aa","a",""]. I experimented on paper, It works with special characters too, but we need to delete them, before we decremented a digit, that comes...

Comment: ... before them. Special cases are the empty string, or a string that consists of only ("A")s, there I will have to think of  a special solution

Comment: Example Descending for Special characters, n = 10: ["b$b", "b$a", "b$", "b", "abb", "aba", "ab", "aaa", "aa", "a", ""]. This is the only way of handling them, that I can think of, to always ensure lexicographcal order, regardless  if they are bigger or smaller than letters in ASCII.

Comment: The fact that you want a a function to *generate* the whole list of results in an array is missing from your question. Your question sounds like one call of the function will give one string as result.

Comment: You are right, I am modifying the question once more. But step by step would be okay too, since I could just place it in an array afterward. But as a reminder, increment is already implemented and working as intended.

Comment: This is not a full solution to your problem, but may give you a good start to solving it: http://link.sauyet.com/85.  We create two functions: one convert a formatted string from your alphabet into a number, and one that converts in the other direction.  You could combine them with an increment in between.  This does not ignore your additional characters, so it is not a complete solution, but might help you get there.  (I will try to post an answer if others also vote to reopen.)

Comment: I did find a little time to try to solve the actual problem.  I don't think your requirements are entirely consistent, but this matches most of them: http://link.sauyet.com/86.  There is too much repetition in `incr` and `decr`, but I don't see an easy way around that.  If this does get reopened, I will try add it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I managed to create both functions by now, and @trincot posted an answer that does the same thing, but with 1/3 of the code. While I did not test his answer fully yet, I think the question can remain closed, since it seems to be pretty much perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `replace` function with regular expression argument to quickly identify the terminating sequence of "z" characters, so you can turn them all into "A".

For decrementing, the logic is to identify a terminating sequence of "A" characters. Those must turn to "z".

And of course, in both cases the digit that precedes that terminating sequence  must increment/decrement.

If there is a foreign character in the input, it should remain unaltered. With this logic it will not be possible to ensure that both functions mirror each other exactly. For instance, if the input is "-A-", then the output of `decrementString()` would remove characters from the end of the string. If that output is given as input to `incrementString()`, then there is no information anymore about that lost hyphen, so that you would get "-A-" again.

To ensure that the lexical order is ensured, more letters may need to be appended at the end of the string. For instance, without such intervention, the input "B" can only be decremented twice ("A" and empty string). By appending a character we can get "Az", "Ay", ... "AA", "A", "".

Here is a solution. The runnable snippet allows you to input some characters and the number of required results, and it will display the output of calling both functions with that input:

```js
const upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
const digits = upper + upper.toLowerCase();

const add = (ch, unit) => digits[digits.indexOf(ch) + unit];

const lettersIn = string => string.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, "");

const valueOf = letters => Array.from(letters).reduce(
    (value, letter) => value * digits.length + digits.indexOf(letter),
    0
);

function incrementString(string, length) {
    const letters = lettersIn(string);
    return digits.length ** letters.length - 1 - valueOf(letters) < length // Not enough digits? 
               ? [string += digits[0], ...incrementString(string, length - 1)] // Add a digit, and retry...
               : Array.from({length}, () =>
                    string = string.replace(/([A-Za-y])([^A-Za-y]*)$/, (_, digit, zz) =>
                        add(digit, 1) + zz.replaceAll(digits.at(-1), digits[0])
                    )
                );
}

function decrementString(string, length) {
    const letters = lettersIn(string);
    const letterValue = valueOf(letters);
    // Count also the possibility to remove characters from the end (string.length):
    return letterValue + string.length < length && letterValue // Need more digits?
                ? decrementString(string + digits[0], length) // Add a digit, and retry...
                : Array.from({length}, () =>
                    string = string.replace(/([B-Za-z])?([^B-Za-z]*)$/, (match, digit, aa) =>
                        digit ? add(digit, -1) + aa.replaceAll(digits[0], digits.at(-1)) : aa.slice(0, -1)
                    )
                );
}

// I/O management

const [inpString, inpCount, outPrev, outNext] = document.querySelectorAll("input, pre");
inpString.addEventListener("input", refresh);
inpCount.addEventListener("input", refresh);

function refresh() {
    const format = (arr) => arr.map(JSON.stringify).join(", ");
    const s = inpString.value;
    const count = +inpCount.value;
    outPrev.textContent = format(decrementString(s, count));
    outNext.textContent = format(incrementString(s, count));
}
refresh();
```

```css
pre { white-space: pre-wrap;}
```

```html
String: <input value="_Z_"><br>
Count: <input value="29" type="number" min="1" max="100"><br>
<table>
<tr><td>Prev:</td><td><pre></pre></td></tr>
<tr><td>Next:</td><td><pre></pre></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is a very helpfull answer, the only thing that I need to find some kind of solution for, if I try to decrement "A$", I will get "$" but, "A$" < "$", I need to find a way to ensure, that a decrement will always be lexicographically smaller, even if it is not the exact inverse of my increment function

Comment: OK, you could have `decrementString` return an empty string when there are no letters anymore. Updated.

Comment: Do I have permission to use your code snippet in my personal project(not monetized)? I can credit you if you want to.

Comment: I really feel bad about an answer that didn't do what you needed. Sorry. If you can let me know what the problem was, I could review it.

Comment: Hello, yes the problem is the following: Most important to me, is lexicographical order increase is always guaranteed. Your solution increments 'z' to 'AA', but 'AA'  <  'z'. So I decided to use your solution n times, and then apply array.sort() to it. This however is still not perfect, here is why. When I do 26 increments on 'a', your solution + sort would give me 'a', 'aA', 'b', ..., 'z'. This poisons the well for future increments. If I know I am going to end up with 2 digits, i would want him to increment like this: 'a', 'aA', 'aB', ' ..., 'aa'. To allow for more increments in the future.

Comment: I am currently working on a solution, and will post my progress here within the next few hours. (On the increment at least). It works by first calculating how many digits will be required for n increments, and then performing the proper increments.

Comment: Oh, but that is information that is missing in the question. If the number of increments is limited then of course you can foresee a number of digits to work with. But your question doesn't include such constraint: that there is only a limited number of increments that will happen. Can you clarify?

Comment: I updated the question once more to make it convey better what I am looking for. I want to thank you for your efforts, it helped me think about my problem more clearly, and finally I manged to finish my own implementation of the increment function. Even though it is beginner Code, I would like to post it as an answer here, but the question is closed. Should I include it in my question? I would like to put it somewhere, so that people looking for a similar algorithm may use or improve it.

Comment: You should not put the answer in the question, as that is not how Stack Overflow works. You can either wait for it to be reopened (I had already cast a vote for that, but it needs more votes), or you can post a new question: but reposting is frowned upon, and may result in down votes.

Comment: I updated my answer in light of the updated question.

Comment: That is a great answer, my code is 3 times as long, but I could not really find any edge cases yet, where yours does not work.